# BBEdit is not recognizing ctags' tags file

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags, bbedit

I'm trying to get BBEdit to recognize my ctags file for a Rails project.  I've tried generating it both with ctags-exuberant directly and with the `bbedit --maketags` command.  While the tags I generate work perfectly in Vim, no such luck in BBEdit.  No error messages or anything, just no symbols trigger completion or allow me to jump.

I've tried moving the tags file into the project directory, no luck.  I've tried generating one lower down in my hierarchy (my models folder) and jumping between model classes, no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: The file system on which my code resides is mounted via osxfuse and seems to be the issue.  When I copy the code to my main drive, tags work exactly like they are supposed to.  I tried symlinking to the folders so my tags file was on my main drive, but still no luck.  For some reason BBEdit doesn't seem to like the code files being on a separate osxfuse filesystem.  That makes no sense to me, I would think all of the work is done with the tags file itself.  Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else comes upon this question like I did, here's the answer from BBEdit support.  In short, if you're using OSX Fuse, do this in Terminal:

defaults write com.barebones.bbedit DisableCtagsScanOnRemoteVolumes -bool NO

Full answer from BBEdit support:

Cribbing from the "Expert Preferences" page of the Help book (Help -> BBEdit Help):

====

** Miscellaneous **

[...]

- When editing files that are on remote file servers (AFP, NFS,
  SMB, etc), BBEdit will not look for directory-relative tags
  files or settings files. This is a particular performance win
  when the file is located on a volume mounted via MacFUSE/SSH or
  similar, or if the file server is over a slow or high-latency link.

  To enable scanning for tags or settings files on remote volumes,
  use these [ Terminal commands ] separately or together:

  defaults write com.barebones.bbedit DisableCtagsScanOnRemoteVolumes -bool NO

  defaults write com.barebones.bbedit DisableSettingsScanOnRemoteVolumes -bool NO

====

Please note that if your only need is for ctags, you need apply only the first option ("DisableCtagsScanOnRemoteVolumes").

Answer (score 2):

From the BBEdit manual (pages 302-304):

> **Using ctags**
>
> BBEdit allows you to generate and use tags files as text completion
>   sources, and will recognize any tags files associated with your
>   documents.
>
> You may place tags files generated via ‘bbedit --maketags’ in the
>   Completion Sources folder of BBEdit’s application support folder (see
>   page 32) for use as text completion sources.
>
> [...]
>
> **Tag Files as Completion Sources**
>
> You can now add tags files to specific locations to make symbols
>   available as completion data sources when editing in desired
>   languages. In particular:
>
> - When you build a (coded) language module, if you place a file named    “tags” in the language module’s “Resources” directory, BBEdit will
>     use those tags as completion sources.
> - You can generate a tags file (using exuberant ctags or “bbedit    --maketags”) and place the resulting file in Application Support/BBEdit/Completion Data/ /, where “
>     name>” is the name of the language as it appears in the list of
>     installed languages (or on the Languages popup menu).
>
> So, for example, if you were to generate a tags file for the 10.6 SDK
>   so that you could add completion data when editing Objective-C files,
>   the file would go in Application Support/ BBEdit/Completion
>   Data/Objective-C/. Tags files can be given any appropriate name, so
>   you can have multiple tags files for a single language, and they will
>   all be examined when generating completions.

And the Completion Data section on p32:

> **Completion Data**
>
> This folder does not exist by default, but you may create it. The
>   Completion Data folder contains tags files (or aliases to tags files)
>   which can provide additional text completions for editing documents in
>   the corresponding languages. These tags files should be in the format
>   generated by ‘bbedit --maketags’, and must be placed in subfolders
>   corresponding to their languages.
>
> Each subfolder should have the exact name of its language as that
>   language appears in the list of installed languages (or on the
>   Languages popup menu).
>
> For example, the subfolder containing a Python tags file must be named
>   “Python”, and the subfolder containing a tags file for ANSI C must be
>   named “ANSI C”.

Comment: Thanks, I'd already tried placing them under the Completion Data folder under Ruby and had the same luck (read, none).  I've read everything I could find in the user guide about these.

Comment: @todd.pierzina just a thought, did you try relaunching BBEdit after placing the tags in the completion folder?

Comment: Yup, restarted every time I tried something different.  Thanks for the thought though!

Comment: See my comment above--this seems to be related to either a separate file system or the fact that it is an osxfuse file system.

Comment: I'd probably send a note to Barebones support and see if they had a solution. They're very responsive.